# Inverse Trigonometric piece-wise functions

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving the equation 
$$2\tan^{-1}(2x-1)=\cos^{-1}x$$

Now while solving the question, the author of the book has written only the first case in the solutions manual.

**CASE I**

$2x-1 \ge 0$ $\rightarrow x\ge 1/2$ $$\Rightarrow 2\tan^{-1}(2x-1)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)$$ 
$$\Rightarrow\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)=\cos^{-1}x$$
and the subsequent equation can be solved now by just using algebraic manipulations.

But I think that there can be one more case in order to solve the equation.

**CASE II**

$2x-1 \le 0$ $\rightarrow x\le 1/2$

**CASE II (Part 1)**

$0\le  x\le 1/2$

$$\Rightarrow 2\tan^{-1}(2x-1)=-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)$$

Because argument of $2\tan^{-1}\phi$ i.e. $\phi= 2x-1 \le 0$

$$\Rightarrow -\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)=\cos^{-1}x$$
and the subsequent equation can be solved now by just using algebraic manipulations.

**CASE II (PART 2)**

$x \in (-1,0)$

In this case both RHS and LHS would come out to be negative and hence ultimately would give the result of the PART 1.

$$\Rightarrow 2\tan^{-1}(2x-1)=-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow -\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)=-\cos^{-1}x$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\right)=\cos^{-1}x$$
and the subsequent equation can be solved now by just using algebraic manipulations.

So am I right about the CASE II (PART 1) or will it result in a unwanted solution (which doesn't satisfy other parameters) and hence the author didn't take this one.

Comment: Case II does not even exist. If $2x-1<0$ then the inverse tangent is a negative angle whereas inverse cosine is always in the interval $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no case II.

If $2x-1<0$ then $2\arctan(2x-1)$ is a negative angle whereas $\arccos(x)$ is never a negative angle.

Therefore if $2x-1<0$

$$2\tan^{-1}(2x-1)\ne \cos^{-1}(x)$$